# Minimize incorrectly reports: There are no points that satisfy the constraints { }

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I've been trying to minimize this:

```
NMinimize[
  {0.0011436611039371792` 
    (-22.749891688107795` - x + Log[0.010964912280701754` a]/(12 π) + 
       Log[0.010964912280701754` b]/(12 π))^2 + 
   0.00028717641571726865` 
     (-20.905057129569222` - x +  Log[0.010964912280701754` a]/(20 π) + 
        Log[0.010964912280701754` b]/(20 π) + Log[0.010964912280701754` c]/(30 π))^2 +       
   0.01400511186583103` 
     (-23.86830932925918` - x + Log[0.010964912280701754` c]/(12 π))^2, 
   1.1690159611663095`*10^14 <= a <= 7.30286103392343`*10^14,  
   4.563696268657563`*10^15 <= b <= 4.56879715466054`*10^15,  
   4.570970079902989`*10^15 <= c <= 6.177387478825724`*10^15}, 
  {x, a, b, c}]
```

But I've been unsuccesful.

Mathematica claims:

> NMinimize::nsol: There are no points that satisfy the constraints {}.

I have tried to plug in several points within the specified constraints and I've got a real number everytime. So as far as I can tell the problem is well defined, mathematically speaking.

Now after playing with the command for a while, I noticed that when I round all the numbers ending with `, I get a result. Like so:

```
NMinimize[
  {0.00114366 
    (-22.7499 - x + Log[0.0109649 a]/(12 π) + Log[0.0109649 b]/(12 π))^2 + 
     0.000287176 
       (-20.9051 - x + Log[0.0109649 a]/(20 π) + Log[0.0109649 b]/(20 π) + 
          Log[0.0109649 c]/(30 π))^2 + 
     0.0140051 (-23.8683 - x + Log[0.0109649 c]/(12 π))^2, 
   1.16902*10^14 <= a <= 7.30286*10^14, 
   4.5637*10^15 <= b <= 4.5688*10^15, 
   4.57097*10^15 <= c <= 6.17739*10^15}, 
  {x, a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {0.00662112,
>  {x -> -22.8238, a -> 1.16902*10^14, b -> 4.5637*10^15, c -> 6.02703*10^15}}
> ```

So I suppose I could use `Round` to round all the long numbers down. However, getting this function takes quite a long code. I would have to use `Round` in a lot of places. Not even mentioning the loss of precision. Is there a quicker way to evaluate the former command without having to use 18 x `Round` all over the code? I haven't found the answer to this anywhere.

Comment: Please, if possible, supply a simpler function to minimize exhibiting the same issue.

Comment: I trimmed it down to this (when I leave more, it starts working and the long numbers are the point, so I cant skip all of those): 

NMinimize[{(-x + 
      Log[0.010964912280701754` a]/(12 \[Pi]))^2 + (Log[
       0.010964912280701754` c]/(12 \[Pi]))^2 + b^2, 
  1.1690159611663095`*10^14 <= a <= 7*10^14, 
  4.563696268657563`*10^15 <= b <= 410^15, 
  4.570970079902989`*10^15 <= c <= 6*10^15}, {x, a, b, c}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a precision problem. This seems to work:

```
NMinimize[SetPrecision[
  {0.0011436611039371792` (-22.749891688107795` - x + 
        Log[0.010964912280701754` a]/(12 π) + 
        Log[0.010964912280701754` b]/(12 π))^2 + 
    0.00028717641571726865` (-20.905057129569222` - x + 
        Log[0.010964912280701754` a]/(20 π) + 
        Log[0.010964912280701754` b]/(20 π) + 
        Log[0.010964912280701754` c]/(30 π))^2 + 
    0.01400511186583103` (-23.86830932925918` - x + 
        Log[0.010964912280701754` c]/(12 π))^2, 
   1.1690159611663095`*10^14 <= a <= 7.30286103392343`*10^14, 
   4.563696268657563`*10^15 <= b <= 4.56879715466054`*10^15, 
   4.570970079902989`*10^15 <= c <= 6.177387478825724`*10^15},
  50
  ], {x, a, b, c},
 WorkingPrecision -> 40]
```

> {0.006618105360153810779221751614203418258948, {
>     x -> -22.82319564674859110474727841393537665003, 
>     a -> 1.169015961166309531250000000000000000000*10^14, 
>     b -> 4.563696268657563000000000000000000000000*10^15, 
>     c -> 6.177387478825724000000000000000000000000*10^15
>      }
>     }

Anyways, the error message is simply wrong and misleading. Please contact support about this issue.